# Trying to export data to CSV with semicolon

Tags: java, csv

I have a code that exports data from an Arraylist with data loaded from a Query to an CSV file, when it storage the data into the arralist, it uses ";" to separate the fields, but when it storage the data into the CSV file, it uses the "," I´m stuck trying to change it. I looked for similar cases and I couldn´t resolve it.

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\personal\\Desktop\\file.csv"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (List<String> element : result) { //result is the name of the Arraylist    
    sb.append(element); 
    sb.append("\n");
}

br.write(sb.toString());
br.close();
```

Comment: shouldn't you map the list to a proper string first?! For example with `element.stream().map(Function.identity()).collect(Collectors.joining(";"))`

Comment: What is your `result`? You are looping a `List<String>`, are you sure it is true? If so, it will return for example, `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, and you are appending this to your `StringBuilder`. If that is you want you can simply use replaceAll method and replace `,` with `;`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I´m doing this to collect the data and 
`try {
Statement st = reg.createStatement();
PreparedStatement pst2=reg.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet res=pst2.executeQuery(); 
int numcols = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
List <List <String> > result = new ArrayList<>();
while (res.next()) {
List <String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols); // new list per row
for (int i=1; i<= numcols; i++) {  // don't skip the last column, use <=
row.add(res.getString(i));
System.out.print(res.getString(i) + ";");
}
result.add(row);
System.out.print("\n");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in the list are stored without any `";"`.
This line:

```
System.out.print(res.getString(i) + ";");
```

prints out the list items with `";"` in between them.
So do this:

```
    for (List<String> line : result) {
        for (String element : line) {
            sb.append(element);
            sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, '\n');
    }
```

Comment: When I add `element = element.replace(";", ",");` . it marks an error :(

Comment: when I changed the `(List<String> element : result)`  for this `(String element : result)` it allows me to do `element = element.replace(";", ",");` but now, the error its marked on `(String element : result)` and the hint tells me to change type of element to this `(List<String> element : result)`

Comment: So your list is a `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: forpas, you did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: in your solution you'll always have a trailing comma - I don't think is is intended.  that's why I'd always prefer the Java 8 based one liner: `element.stream().map(Function.identity()).collect(Collectors.joining(";"))`

Comment: @AKSW you did not see `sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, '\n');`?